# Why do browsers encode special characters differently with ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, character-encoding

I have a web application that reads the values of a few input fields (alphanumeric) and constructs a very simple xml that is passes to the server, using jQuery's $.ajax() method.
The template for that xml is:

```
<request>
    <session>[some-string]</session>
    <space>[some-string]</space>
    <plot>[some-string]</plot>
    ...
</request>
```

Sending such requests to the server when the inputs contain Finnish diacritical characters (such as **ä** or **ö**) raises a problem in terms of character encoding with different browsers. For instance, if I add the word **Käyttötarkoitus**" in one of the inputs, here's how Chrome and Firefox send EXACTLY the same request to the server:

***Chrome:***

```
<request>
    <session>{string-hidden}</session>
    <space>2080874</space>
    <plot>KÃ¤yttÃ¶tarkoitus</plot>
    ...
</request>
```

***FF 12.0:***

```
<request>
    <session>{string-hidden}</session>
    <space>2080874</space>
    <plot>Käyttötarkoitus</plot>
    ...
</request>
```

And here is the code fragment that I use to send the requests:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: url,
    dataType: 'xml;charset=UTF-8',
    data: xml, 
    success: function(xml) { 
        //
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //
    }
});
```

Why do I get different encodings and how do I get rid of this difference? I need to fix this problem because it's causing other on the server-side.

Comment: What's the encoding of the containing HTML page?

Comment: Remember to set correct charset on the file itself.

Comment: everything must be utf8 : page encoding (save the file with utf8 without BOM, add a meta charset), server encoding (in Php, set utf8 in the .htaccess config file), database encoding (set names with mySQL)...

Comment: @Emil Vikström UTF-8 is the char encoding for the HTML document. But the xml I pasted above was taken from Firebug and Chrome's code Inspector

Comment: @mdi The problem is on the client-side, in the sense that Chrome's code inspector and Firefox's Firebug send out different types of characters. While Chrome replaces the diacritical ones with combinations of other chars, Firefox doesn't...

Comment: What @Andrei said. You can't trust the output of Firebug or Code Inspector in this case.

Answer (score 0):

On dataType, try putting "application/xml" or "text/xml" instead of "xml;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: No luck with this change, Miguel. Any other ideas?

Comment: Just a wild guess so... try using the $.param() function to encode the XML. I normally use JSON for AJAX requests but worths the try...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the param method, I have some server restrictions. I can only send data like it's being sent now. Just have to figure out why the difference in encoding between browsers.

Comment: Couldn't you encode the strings separately and then build the xml?

Comment: I remember that I had a similar issue some time ago... I'm just not remembering how I solved though... Don't know if I found a function to escape those special characters or if I changed everything to JSON. However, I'm pretty positive that there must be some escape function in jquery framework to do it (or at lying somewhere on the internet)

edit: I'm know this function is deprecated but try using the escape function. I know this is not the ideal solution but may give some hint on how to solve the issue (if the characters are correctly represented on server side)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12686/discussion-between-andrei-oniga-and-miguel-ribeiro)

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURI to encode uri.. And you will have to decode it in server too.I have the same problem.I am searching for a better option since encodeURI encodes date fields too